# Trying to find urban fantasy book from a Facebook ad 2019/20

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I am looking for a book that popped up in an Amazon Facebook ad that I wanted to read but once the ad passed I never was able to find it again.

Urban fantasy and it was a immortal wizard that was tired of living. In hoping to die he found a confluence of events that opened a window for him to pass on but before it can happen he gets information that his daughter or lover was kidnapped. Sorry if this isn't enough info.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *[Immortal Redeemed](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29006942-immortal-redeemed)* by Linda Thomas-Sundstrom?

> Only one woman holds the key to ending a Blood Knight's eternal life…
>
> Immortal Kellan Ladd has spent centuries looking for the one woman who can put an end to his immortality. But that woman has no idea of her monumental task. Or how much this rebel knight's attraction to her will complicate his mission.
>
> The leather-clad, Harley-riding stranger was the sexiest man McKenna Randall had ever met. From the minute they touched, she knew they were connected. Now she's about to find out just how tightly bound they are when they must go head-to-head with a nest of deadly vampires…

Comment: No its a similar premise but thanks for the recommendation. The book was the start of a new series and i have never been able to find it past that one ad. It vexes me.